# UIF to ISO disk image converter

Tags: windows, gratis, file-converter, disk-image

I'm looking for a .UIF to .ISO disk image converter. I would like this software to meet these requirements,

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A freeware script called "UIF to ISO" does the job. It meets my requirements of being,

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10

It's simple and easy to use and converts discs in a matter of seconds.

## [UIF to ISO](http://www.uiftoiso.com/) (free)

> UIF to ISO is a free software that can convert UIF image format to ISO image format. You can simply select the file you want to convert, then press the "Convert" button to start conversion, the default generated ISO file have the same file name with the original file, just the file extension is ".iso", easy to use so much.
>
> [image: UIF to ISO UI]